# How to get list of timezones with cities?

Tags: java, android

can someone explain how to get list of timezones with GMT offset from current time?

For instance: **current time is 15:20** so items of list should be
16:20 UTC+1 Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna
17:20 UTC+2 Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius
and so on   
If get cities so complicated just show how do this without it

**Regards!**

Comment: Have you tried using this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html

Comment: David Jones, it's useful information but in Android cannot be imported a few classes

Comment: Do you mean this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#List_of_UTC_offsets

Comment: **Der Golem** something like this

Comment: @user2950872 I am not aware of any open source APIs or libraries which returns cities in different time zones. You can either create your own database to store these information, or check out the new link to a **paid** service I added to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the timezone, the GMT offset and the different local current times using the [`Timezone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) class and the [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class like this:

```
for(String timezone : Timezone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(timezone);

    // or do whatever you want with these
    System.out.println("AM_PM: " + calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
    System.out.println("HOUR: " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    System.out.println("HOUR_OF_DAY: " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    System.out.println("MINUTE: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    System.out.println("SECOND: " + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    System.out.println("MILLISECOND: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    System.out.println("ZONE_OFFSET: " + (calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)/(60*60*1000)));
}
```

As for retrieving information about local cities in each timezone, I am not aware of any open source APIs or libraries which do that. There is this **paid** [Time API](http://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/time-api.html). But you can always create your own database to store them.

Comment: **isim**  I edited your code a little and partly got all that I need

Comment: @user2950872 Glad that works. If you like the answer, please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks!